# MVC C# Invalidate Cache for particular user from admin part

Tags: c#, caching, model-view-controller, invalidation

Is it possible and how as a general idea to invalidate a cache for a user while the application is running.
The scenario is that I am going to store permissions in cache, but when an admin changes a permission for user, then his cache should be invalidated and update the cache.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this won't work. The users have unique Session that can't be accessed by each other.

What you could do is, write a flag into your database and then refresh the permissions.
But that would lead to a database read everytime the user does an Action.

The way we did it, is to show a message to the admin, that the user must log out and log in again to get the new permissions.

You could also give the users the possibility to reload their permissions.

Comment: I think you are right, but one other idea to be able to invalidate the user cache is to use application System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application object. I have done one small prove of concept project which seems to be working. The idea is that on the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application object I am storing under userid key and object which describes the cache - if is invalid or not. This can be accessible by all users. So when the user access cache from session - first checks that key. A diagram which can explain that is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46512232/Caching.pdf

Comment: Do you think that this is sensible? I am not sure that I want to tight the cache with data dependancy. Application will be light enough - will have key and value of some small object, but could not be the best if thousands users are using the system, although this will be set only when admin invalidates the cache - edit user permissions.